# Cannot understand the "Layout forced" section in DevTools performance tab

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I am studying the Chrome DevTools Performance Tab based on this article https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/.

In step 7, it said "In the Summary tab, click the app.js:70 link under Layout Forced. DevTools takes you to the line of code that forced the layout.", it indicate **line 70**:

[image]

But actually the change of the style should occurs in line 69, i.e.:

```
m.style.top = pos + 'px';
```

Why it will highlight line 70 instead?

Comment: Using `elem.offsetTop` causes the browser to force a layout/repaint. See: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: @skyline3000, Thank you for your explanation. Now I understand that.